# Server 2019: slow upload

Tags: networking, tcp, windows-10, windows-server-2019

I have both Windows 10 Pro and Server 2019 VMs set up on the same host.

From the Server 2019 instance, using `iperf` and the same NIC/driver as the Windows 10 guest, I get ~3Mbps on a theoretically 100Mbps link. The Windows 10 guest gets me ~40Mbps using the same iperf flags.

I used PowerShell's `Get-NetTCPSetting` on both and then `diff`'d the results; I adjusted the `EcnCapability`, `InitialRtoMs` and `MaxSynRetransmissions` settings on the Windows 10 instance to match those of Server 2019. However, I still get good throughput on the W10 instance. I'm trying to hunt down the source of the massive difference and I thought the TCP stack would be a good place to look. Having equalized the settings I can think of, I'm now at a loss. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try these
I issued the following PowerShell commands to restore performance
https://www.justinho.com/blog/2020/05/30/Windows-Server-2019-vRSS-Hyper-V.html